# how to create degrees symbol in XAML

Tags: xaml

Is there a simple way to display a degrees symbol (as in Fahrenheit) in XAML? Ive been able to find solutions in HTML, Android and iPhone but nothing in xaml.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the same code/number used in HTML

This shows Shows "55º"

```
<TextBlock Text="55&#186;"/>
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using this method versus just pasting the symbol in?

Answer (score 6):

Is this: " ° " the symbol you're looking for?  I recommend just copying/pasting it into your XAML code and it should display properly.

Answer (score 5):

The correct HTML code is 176, according to [this](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) link. The code 186 is masculine ordinal indicator. So the correct answer would be

```
<TextBlock Text="&#176;F"/>
```

This will show "°F".